# Is it possible to show a different record in a Bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-modal

I currently have a html table with the basic data of a record:

Orderid - Order description - Order wish date

What i'm trying to do is show the data from another datbase-table in a bootstrap modal when clicked on the table row:

Itemid-Orderid-Quantity

I can pass the Orderid to JS when clicking on the table row and op a modal.

I don't know how or if it's even possible to show the other data in the modal.
(data should be editable in the modal).

html code from the table row:

```
    <tr data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?=$uitleen['uid']?>" data-target="#orderModal">               

<td> 

    <input type="hidden" name="uid" value="<?=$uitleen['uid']?>" /> 
     <div style="float:left;margin-right:5px;margin-left:1em" class="activiteit"> <?=$uitleen['activiteit']?> </div>
        </td>   
<td class="naam"> <?=$uitleen['naam']?> </td>
<td class="speltak"> <?=$uitleen['speltak']?> </td>
<td class="datum"> <?=$uitleen['datumuit']?> </td>
<td style="width:40em;" class=""> <?=$uitleen['opmerking']?> </td>


        </tr>
```

Code to trigger the modal:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#orderModal').modal({
        keyboard: true,
        backdrop: "static",
        show:false,

    }).on('show', function(){ //subscribe to show method
          var getIdFromRow = $(event.target).closest('tr').data('id'); //get the id from tr
        //make your ajax call populate items or what even you need
        $(this).find('#orderDetails').html($('<b> Order Id selected: ' + getIdFromRow  + '</b>'))
    });
}); 
        </script>
```

What i would like to do is show data from another datbase table in the modal. The records i need al contain the 'uid'

something like this:

uid - item 1 - quantity
uid - item 2 - quantity
etc.

the quantity should be editable.

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: can u share the code , just to uderstand better your situation

Comment: *"data from another table"* ... does that mean html table or database table? Question is really lacking in details and a [mcve]

Comment: added the code.. and hopefully made a better description. Data from another table means from another database table.